# Linking of Words/headers in Obsidian not working

Tags: debugging, markdown, obsidian

So, in an attempt to keep a separate document in a container, I have started using Obsidian for my studies. While trying to record my notes, I realised that If I can link listed items and the beginning of the document and later explain the meaning of those words in a later part of the same document, that would work wonders for me. Like the explaination given in the below video by Gwen of Faraday Academy

[check at minute 18:51](https://youtu.be/bTVIMt3XllM?t=1131)

However, the same step if I try to replicate in Obsidian, is not working. The display is not moving to the target location.

So, please, can anybody help me with this who has experience working with Obsidian markdown files. Thanks!

Comment: Are you referring to internal links: https://help.obsidian.md/Linking+notes+and+files/Internal+links

Comment: Internal links yes. But, it is in the same markdown file That I am working on. Not to a different markdown file.

Comment: Suppose you are reading an ebook with hundreds of pages. At the beginning of the book the all contents of the books are listed chapter wise. Now you want to read a chapter which is on page 200. So, to do it you click on the appropriate listed name which is there at the beginning of the book and you are taken to that chapter on the 200th page in the same book.

in my case mostly what is happening is that a new pdf is opening up  instead of taking me to the 200th page of the same pdf.

Comment: To clarify: are you trying to open a PDF file from obsidian, or just jump to another location in the current markdown file?

Comment: the PDF was an example of what I am trying to do in a markdown file in Obsidian.

Comment: According to the documentation you can use `[[#MyHeading]]` to create a link to a heading (a line starting with `# MyHeading`) in the same document